# Excel: looking for a value in a specific range

Tags: vba, excel

I have over 3000 values in column A. I have a value of x in column B. I want excel to look through the values in column A and give back a "yes" if there is a value bigger  than x, yet smaller than x+7 (x+7>value to be found in column A >x). If such value(s) does not exist, then display "no"

Here's an example:

Column A

2: 11.2

3: 11.3

4: 11.4

5: 13.5

6: 13.6

7: 20.5

8: 20.6

9: 30.5

Column B

2: 11.1

3: 20.7

In this case, since there are values in Column 1 that are bigger than 11.1 and within the range (smaller than B2+7, and bigger than B2), I need excel to give back "yes". If possible, it would be ideal to also give the first value after the specific value in column B.

Here's what I have tried so far but have had no success: 
=IF(AND((B2+7)>A1:A3000>B2),"yes","no") 
=IF(AND((B2+7)>$A$2:$A$3000,$A$2:$A$3000>B2),"yes","no")

How can I do this in Excel? is there a way to do this other than using IF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (for cell `B2`)

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A:A>B2)*(A:A<B2+7)),"Yes","No")
```

and copy down as far as required.

For the second part, to return the next larger value, try this

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A:A>B2)*(A:A<B2+7)),INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B2,A:A,1)+1),"No")
```

Note that this requires the data in column `A` to be sorted ascending (as your sample ata is) and for cell `A` to contain '0'.  If these conditions are not possible, then you might have to consider a VBA user defined function.

Comment: Do you know how I could get the first number after B2 if the answer is "yes"?

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I am not understanding the question, but isn't the answer:

```
=IF(AND((B2+7)>$A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10>B2),"yes","no")
```

Where that would be the equation in C2, testing B2 for entries in the list that spans A2 - A10.  You'd copy that equation down the column for all the entries in B column.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you require but maybe `=IF(AND(A2>B$2,A2<B$2+7),"yes","no")` copied down would serve to test B2 and B2+7 against each of the Column A values.